# Grails - multiple joins shows redundant data in the list view

Tags: grails

I'm trying to sort the list, but need to join in order to sort. The code, I'm using is like below. If I don't sort, then it gives me the right data, but when sorting like below it joins with multiple tables which causes to show redundant data in my result because some tables have relation of one-to-many.

```
def result = Server.createCriteria().list() {
                connection {
                    customerLocation {
                        eq("customer", customer.id)
                    }
                }
                serverSide {
                    clientSide {
                        clientSideMachine {
                            domain {
                                order "DomainName", "asc"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

I want to show

```
A1 A2 A3
B1 B2 B3
C1 C2 C3
```

in my list but above code generates redundant data due to joins...

```
A1 A2 A3
A1 A2 A3
A1 A2 A3
B1 B2 B3
B1 B2 B3
C1 C2 C3
C1 C2 C3
```

Is there an easy way to handle this??? I'm also using pagination in GSP.

Answer (score 1):

To remove the duplicates you can specify list distinct however be warned this destroys pagination.

```
criteria.listDistinct
```

instead of `list`